# Spark+Scala: Forcing action not enforced?

Tags: scala

I have the following code that is supposed to do computation over many files. The computation should happen at any point of time only over a specified number of files (`nFiles`). I have inserted a `println` statement on the output list show to its length thereby forcing it to completing processing of all the `nFiles`. But the code is gobbling too much work that results in missing heartbeats and subsequent killing of the jobs altogether. What am I doing wrong here?

```
var subFiles = new MutableListBuffer[String]()
while (queue.size > 0) {
    val qSize = queue.size
    val lSize = fullDataList.size
    println(s"Queue size = $qSize ; List size = $lSize")

    (1 to nFiles) foreach (x => if (queue.size > 0) {
        subFiles.append(queue.dequeue())
    })

    val data = subFiles.par.map { x => ncToList(x) }
    val subList = data.reduce(_ union _)
    subFiles.clear()

    fullDataList = fullDataList ++ subList
}
```

The following output is obtained in a very little time (demonstrating action over list not being completed) followed by a large inactive state:

```
Queue size = 20000 ; List size = 0
Queue size = 18000 ; List size = 100000
Queue size = 16000 ; List size = 200000
Queue size = 14000 ; List size = 300000
Queue size = 12000 ; List size = 400000
```

I also tried printing the last element of the list, but again the problem remains though it does print element too fast. It appears that Scala is simply providing the answer without applying transformations, which appears very confusing. Where am I going wrong?

Modified code has 2 extra lines at the bottom

```
    ...
    fullDataList = fullDataList ++ mergedDataList
    val maxTime = fullDataList(fullDataList.size - 1)._1
    println(s"Queue size = $qSize ; List size = $lSize; Max time = $maxTime")
}
```

The corresponding output after 20 min is:

```
Queue size = 20000 ; List size = 0; Max time = 200000.0 (Sun Jul 16 17:53:31 UTC 2023)
Queue size = 18000 ; List size = 100000; Max time = 300000.0 (Sun Jul 16 17:53:44 UTC 2023)
Queue size = 16000 ; List size = 200000; Max time = 400000.0 (Sun Jul 16 17:53:57 UTC 2023)
Queue size = 14000 ; List size = 300000; Max time = 500000.0 (Sun Jul 16 17:54:41 UTC 2023)
```

Comment: Is Spark involved or not? You mention it but your code is just plain Scala.

Comment: This was run within Spark.

Comment: I don't think Spark plays any role here. What is important though are the symetics related to the existence of `queue`,  `fullDataList`, `nFiles`. Also what is this `ncToList` function? And I think it is pretty normal for Scala to be able to iterate a list of 20,000 strings in around 1 second (as long as that `ncToList` function is not very comlex)... what is the problem here ?

Comment: You probably need to rewrite it so that it _actually_ uses spark ... My guess, is that loading 20,000 files into memory on the same machine just uses up all the memory, so you get stuck in a gc loop .

Comment: I have done the same and it solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally solve the problem by doing the following to make Spark-based solution. First I made a Spark Dataset with a column containing the file names using a case class and then using the method of the case class and `.map()` of the Dataset, I created output using pure Spark approach.